# Change all products to have the same shipping class within Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a woocommerce shop with 1000+ products in it, however, I've notices that random products have no shipping class applied to them. So when customers get to the checkout, these items cause issues with shipping calculations.

Is there any way to show a list of products with no shipping class, or change all products in the shop to the same shipping class without going through each products individually?

I know i could use bulk actions to change them all, but there's 25+ pages, even when I change the amount of products shown.

Answer (score 0):

This should change the shipping class of all the published posts.

**Updated answer**

Just remembered about the [fields](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter) parameter, so this is the new code:

```
$shipping_class_slug = 'your-shipping-class-slug';

// get just the IDs of all products published
$products = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids'
));

// for each product change the shipping class
foreach ( $products->posts as $pID ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $pID, $shipping_class_slug, 'product_shipping_class' );
}
```

**Old answer**

```
$shipping_class_slug = 'your-shipping-class-slug';

// get all products published
$products = new WP_Query( array (
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
));

// retrieve products IDs
$productsIDs = wp_list_pluck( $products->posts, 'ID' );

// for each product change the shipping class
foreach ( $productsIDs as $pID ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $pID, $shipping_class_slug, 'product_shipping_class' );
}
```

You can wrap it in a function (in your functions.php file) to call with an [action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action).

Remember to change `'your-shipping-class-slug'` with the one you want.

And most of all: **DO A BACKUP** before you try anything! ;)

(better: clone the website locally and try there first)